# Writing complex data structures in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I am basically trying to write a datastructure in shell (basically classes )

Something like following

```
foo = Foo()
foo.add_value(1)
etc
```

But I realized that probably shell is not the place to do this (Please correct me if i am wrong)

Now the other way I thought was writing a C++ or python code with these datastructures and have shell script parse the values to the compiled binaries or executable scripts..

Something like in shell I write the function as

```
  function Foo()
  {
    #call the binaries
    echo $something out
  }
```

but how do I create that foo.method() type of experience??

Any suggestions will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://shoop.sourceforge.net.

> This is the Shoop: SHell Object Oriented Programming project
>   ("shoop")
>
> This project was registered on SourceForge.net on Apr 11, 2006, and is
>   described by the project team as follows:
>
> Shoop: SHell Object Oriented Programming extends POSIX shell to have
>   OO suport, adding classless object orientation (introspection,
>   finalization, serialization, multiple inheritance ) to plain old shell
>   script.